# Como posso somar um valor a uma row no bd sem ter que tar a somar variaveis?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom a minha pergunta é assim:

Eu tenho a row saldo de um determinado usuário da minha tabela do banco de dados que tem 100€, e eu queria somar +50€, como o poderei fazer sem ter que tar a criar uma variavel com o saldo atual dele, mais uma variavel com o saldo a adicionar, mais uma variavel com a soma dos dois valores e aí inserir no banco de dados.

Existe alguma forma mais rápida de somar valores ao banco de dados sem ter que tar sempre a fazer este processo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, depende de como estão os dados na sua tabela, se estiverem junto com texto 100€ você terá que tratar primeiro retirando o texto na querie que pode ser utilizando replace, depois terá que converter para número e depois efetuar a soma, caso esteja sem o texto porem contenha ponto 100.55 poderá fazer a soma normal na própria querie como os amigos informaram nas respostas abaixo.

Comment: Francamente sua pergunta não está clara, exemplifique com o código atual e o que queres otimizar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem de ter a certeza que o tipo de dado que essa coluna (neste caso `saldo`) armazena é numérico.

Para selecionar os resultados para que só sejam apresentados os dados com + 50. Pode fazer:

```
SELECT saldo + 50 as saldo FROM tabela;
```

Mas se quiser mesmo fazer o update à coluna em todas as linhas:

```
UPDATE tabela SET saldo = saldo + 50;
```

Ou fazer update noutra coluna em todas as linhas:

```
UPDATE tabela SET saldo2 = saldo1 + 50;
```

Para especificar que quer que estas ações sejam impostas em determinadas linhas da tabela, especifique quais as linhas complementando qualquer dos exemplos acima (apague o `;` do final) com:

```
... WHERE id = 3;
```

Neste caso quero que só seja executado o comando ([query](http://pplware.sapo.pt/tutoriais/vamos-dar-uns-toques-em-queries-sql/)) na(s) linha(s) cuja coluna id for igual a 3

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54234/discussion-on-answer-by-miguel-como-posso-somar-um-valor-a-uma-row-no-bd-sem-ter)

Answer (score 9):

A forma mais rápida que eu conheço seria usando apenas um `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tbl_usuario SET vl_saldo = vl_saldo + 50 WHERE id_usuario = 123;
```

Comment: Queria usar o select, era melhor para evitar bugs no meu bd, pois são bastantes registos.

Comment: @Gonçalo: Você pretende inserir em outra tabela os valores somados ?

Comment: Pretendo inserir na mesma tabela, mas com select.

Comment: Como assim pretende inserir com um `select`?

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT saldo FROM tabela;

    while (...) 
     {
      saldo =saldo +50;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente seria algo parecido com isso.
Note que talvez você precise consistir os campos únicos ou chaves primárias da tabela e nomear os campos na mesma ordem da criação da tabela. Para melhor detalhamento favor postar as colunas da tabela

```
insert into tabela select campo1,campo2...,valor+50 from tabela where usuario = idUsuario
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria um Stored Procedure

no seu mySQL command (penso que vc esteja usando mySQL)

a primeira linha troqua o delimiter do sql

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS addSaldo(IN costumerName VARCHAR(255), IN valor INT)
 BEGIN
 Select campo seus queries aqui .......
 adicione usando variable valor ......
 WHERE ...... = costumerName;   
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

ultima linha troca o delimeter de volta para ";"

para usar agora use o query

```
 CALL addSaldo("nomeDoCliente", valorASerAdicionado);
```

usando esse method vc tera melhor eficiencia , melhor manuntencao e mais seguranca.

se vc quiser fazer fora do mySQL command (facil manutencao)

1) crie uma file addSaldo.sql

2) coloque o codigo acima dentro dessa file e salve

3) rode o comando (Linux)

```
mysql -u root -pSenhaDoRoot NomeDaDatabase < addSaldo.sql
```

pronto , caso vc queira fazer futura mudanca e so mudar na file , fazer um drop na procedure e rodar esse comando.

como nao sei a estrutura de sua table nao tem como te ajudar no format dos queries.